# webpack not loading my font files

Tags: javascript, node.js, fonts, webpack

As has happened to many others before, webpack is simply not loading any of my fonts into the build. I've looked at the boards, searched google, tried many different regex tricks and tried other techniques like the copy-webpack-plugin from npm. The build is run via a generic 'npm start'. Please take a look at the below directory structure and my webpack build file and tell me what I might be missing. Thx :-P

Directory Structure (folders in CAPS):

```
/
 - index.html
 - index.js
 - webpack.config.js
 - server.js
 ASSETS
  FONTS
   <font files>
 COMPONENTS
 CONTAINERS, etc..
```

my webpack file (test for fonts at the bottom):

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    'eventsource-polyfill',
    'whatwg-fetch',
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: [ 'react-hot', 'babel' ],
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      include: __dirname
    }, {
      test: /\.css?$/,
      loaders: [ 'style', 'raw' ],
      include: __dirname
    },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loaders: ['style', 'css', 'less'],
        include: __dirname
      },
      { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff" },
      { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" }]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never needed all the regex in the test.

Example of one of my webpack files:

```
module: {
loaders: [
    // Javascript
    { test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: 'babel', exclude: /node_modules/ },
    // Stylesheets
    { test: /\.scss$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap!sass?sourceMap') },
    // Font Definitions
    { test: /\.svg$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=image/svg+xml&name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]' },
    { test: /\.woff$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/font-woff&name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]' },
    { test: /\.woff2$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/font-woff2&name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]' },
    { test: /\.[ot]tf$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/octet-stream&name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]' },
    { test: /\.eot$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=application/vnd.ms-fontobject&name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]' }
  ]
},
```

Comment: I just tried your regex for the font files, unfortunately no files in the build . . . for what it is worth I have no fancy scripts to do my build, just a generic  'npm start'